# TimeToFirstByte problem in joomla

Tags: joomla-3.x, seo, server-response-time

my site was working fine till a few months ago thanks to "jch plugin" and "cache plugin" and page load time improved to 3 seconds and response time under 1 second.

but suddenly response time went up to 7 seconds.

when i turned back a backup from 8 month ago, the page loads in 3 seconds. so i guess the problem isn't from the server. i updated everything in the old backup and still page load time was 3 second. so i guess the problem isn't coming from updated extensions and Joomla (I GUESS)

i turned on "joomla debug" and i didn't see anything wrong in it. maybe i didn't check it right.

what are the ways that can help me find out why TimeToFirstByte is high?
what can i do to find the problem?

is there any plugin or something that shows what happens in ttfb time?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This might be caused by one of your plugins. Try disabling your plugins one by one until the response time increases.

If that doesn't help, then scan your website for anything malicious, it might be hacked.

I checked CloudFlare's article "Stop Worrying About Time to First Byte" (the link to the article is in the previous answer), and I certainly don't agree with their motives in writing the article. The only reason they are doing so is to justify their relatively high TTFB, and not because TTFB is "meaningless".

TTFB is same as server response time, and is measured in microsends in Google's Search Console, and there's actually a chart about it in Google's Search Console (I think in the "Crawl Stats" page). It is important (that's why Google constantly monitors it and alerts you if it's too high) and don't let CloudFlare or other firms with specific agendas tell you otherwise.

Comment: Additional: A comment about the TTFB from Ilya Grigorik (Google web performance engineer) back in 2012: https://plus.google.com/+IlyaGrigorik/posts/GTWYbYWP6xP

Answer (score 0):

May be the old Software was sending a first Byte before everthing was rendered.
Is the download time (Request to finish download) changed too?
Her is a [article](https://blog.cloudflare.com/ttfb-time-to-first-byte-considered-meaningles/) to keep in mind if you test TTFB.